# Try to understand handlers function in Go

Tags: go, http, handler

I was trying to do this practice: https://go.dev/doc/articles/wiki/ from the Golang documentation and I am not understanding something. In the second part of the article, when we started using "net/http" package we wrote this(I left the code more complete here: https://go.dev/doc/articles/wiki/part2.go):

```
 func viewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    title := r.URL.Path[len("/view/"):]

    p, _ := loadPage(title)

    fmt.Fprintf(w, "<h1>%s</h1><div>%s</div>", p.Title, p.Body)

}


func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/view/", viewHandler)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))

}
```

I am not understanding why viewHandler is in the arguments of http.HandleFunc without the two arguments defined above. Because, in the definition of viewHandler there are two arguments: w and r? When/who complete that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go supports using function signatures as parameters to other functions. This is a powerful feature in Go known as "[first-class functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)."

In Go, functions are first-class citizens, meaning you can pass functions as parameters to other functions and even return functions from functions. This capability is particularly useful for creating higher-order functions and handling callbacks.

Here's a shorter example:

```golang
type BinaryOperation func(int, int) int

func Apply(operation BinaryOperation) int {
    return operation(5, 5)
}

func main() {
    // Define an addition function inline
    sum := Apply(func(a, b int) int { return a + b })
    fmt.Println(sum) // 10

    // Define a subtraction function inline
    difference := Apply(func(a, b int) int { return a - b })
    fmt.Println(difference) // 0
}
```

---

Additionally, understanding the concept of callbacks helps you comprehend this code.

A callback is a common programming concept that involves passing a function as an argument to another function and executing this function when a certain event occurs or a specific condition is met. Callbacks are typically used to implement asynchronous operations, event handling, and timing tasks, among other scenarios.

A simple callback example：

```golang
func eventHandler(event string, callback func(string)) {
    fmt.Println("Event:", event)
    callback(event)
}

func main() {
    eventHandler("Button Click", func(event string) {
        fmt.Println("Handling", event)
    })

    eventHandler("File Save", func(event string) {
        fmt.Println("Saving", event)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> why viewHandler is in the arguments of http.HandleFunc without the two arguments defined above.

`viewHandler` is the name of a function.  you're supplying a function that will be called to handle requests to `/view/`.  Your code wouldn't compile if `viewHandler` failed to match the function signature in the argument to `http.HandleFunc`.

> in the definition of viewHandler there are two arguments: w and r? When/who complete that?

The http server code will supply that when it runs your function to handle the request.   [http.HandleFunc](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#HandleFunc) takes a function that is passed an `http.ResponseWriter` - a place to write the response - and an `*http.Request` - a structure representing the request.  When an actual request comes in, it will be passed to your function, along with an `http.ResponseWriter` through which you send your response.